# What does it mean to represent elements of an ideal?

Tags: galois-theory, ideals, finite-fields, coding-theory

Say I have the polynomial $x^9 + 1$

Then: $x^9 + 1 = (x+1)(x^2 + x + 1)(x^6 + x^3 + 1)$

is a complete factorization over $GF(2)$ of  $x^9 + 1$

The dimension of each ideal is: length $n - deg(ideal)$

So for $n=9$, dimension of $(x+1)$ = $9-1=8$

of $(x^2 + x + 1) = 9 - 2 = 7$

of $(x^6 + x^3 + 1) = 9 - 6 = 3$

So let's use $(x^6 + x^3 + 1)$ as the example. The dimension is 3. So there should be $2^3 = 8$ elements. How do I find those elements?

Comment: Your question is a bit lacking in the description of the ideals. For the question to make sense you must be asking about the ideals of $R=GF(2)[x]/\langle x^9+1\rangle$. This is also the algebraic universe where cyclic codes of length 9 reside, so it fits. It is also what Lubin used in his answer. These polynomials also generate ideals in the ring $GF(2)[x]$, but those ideals are all infinite dimensional. Sorry about nitpicking, I am not done with my morning coffee yet. After all, it was clear to me that ideals of $R$ were intended.

Comment: Yes sorry about that. Thought I included it was ideals of $R$.

Comment: Yes, @JyrkiLahtonen, I had to ponder deeply to divine what OP was seeking, and originally thought his question was something entirely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s call $f=x^6+x^3+1$. You want three linearly independent elements of the ideal $(f)$ of the ring $R=\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^9+1)$. Since $(f)$ is just the set of multiples of $f$, you certainly have $1\cdot f$, $xf$, and $x^2f$. Notice that $x^3f=x^9+x^6+x^3=1+x^6+x^3=1\cdot f$, already counted. I’ll leave it to you to show that those three polynomials are $\Bbb F_2$-linearly independent in $R$.

Comment: I think I get it now. So for the $f$ above, I basically multiply any of the combinations of $x^2 + x + 1$ by $f$ ? So $0, 1, x, x+1, x^2, x^2 + 1, etc$.

Comment: Maybe you have it, but you’ve not expressed it quite right. You multiply any $\Bbb F_2$-linear combination of elements from $\{x^2,x,1\}$ by $f$. It has nothing to do with the polynomial $1+x+x^2$, except that this is one of those linear combinations. Don’t forget that since your field has just the two elements, a linear combination as I specified above simply corresponds to a subset of that set with three elements. There’s your $8=2^3$ things. Things would be quite different over a field with $>2$ elements; that’s why it’s best to talk about the dimension of your ideal as a vector space.